# Hosting .NET method in SQL Server CLR

Tags: .net, sql, clr-hosting

I have been asked to create a function in SQL Server 2005 that is a CLR hosted function I have created in .NET 3.5. Do CLR functions hosted in SQL have access to App.Config files or do all config options need to be passed as paramaters?

Comment: Do you mean C# 3.0 or .NET 3.5? Either is fine, but there's no such thing as C# 3.5 :)

Comment: SQL CLR only supports .NET-Framework 2.0

Comment: SQL Server 2008 supports .NET-Framework 3.5 and continues to load the version 2.0 CLR.  Version 4.0 CLR is available, but SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 continue to load version 2.0 CLR intentionally.  http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/10/16/sql-server-2008-sqlclr-net-framework-version/

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server CLR function runs on the server.
App.Config is on the client.

So, It would not be very logical to me, if a SQL Server CLR function can access the App.Config that is sitting on the client ...